# When no records found throwing Exception in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Below is my code i am checking `TransmediaTable` and filtering.

I manually created a case to satisfy the condition and giving expected results. But when taken new sample the result throwing exception `Object reference not set to Instance of Object`.
Where i am going wrong.

```
var MissedTransmedias = XMLOperations.TransmediaTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME").Contains("CAB:DSLAM") &&
                x.Field<String>("BT_CABLE_TYPE") == "BFT" &&
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<String>("TO_EQUIPMENT_NAME")) &&
                ((x.Field<String>("BT_CABLE_DESIGNATION") + x.Field<String>("BT_CABLE_NUMBER")) == OnNumber))
    .Select(x => x.Field<String>("TRANSMEDIA_NAME"));
```

Comment: what do you mean by "But when taken new sample"? empty table? new entry in table that does NOT satisfy "the condition"?

Comment: Split that query to find out the specific offending code

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this `x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME").Contains("CAB:DSLAM")` is your problem, `x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME")` is `null` at some entry.

Comment: This is potential plase where you can get that exception `x => x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME").Contains("CAB:DSLAM")`.

Comment: Actually i am converting xml data into DataTable. New sample means new xml file and new data.

Comment: @Jagadesh of course the `data` is new but the `xml structure` should be fixed and defined as the standard format. You should check for the existence of `Attribute` before calling anything on it. I'm not familiar with `XML stuff`, but I remember that we have some way to check the valid format of an `XML file` based on some `xsd file` to ensure it's valid before reading it.

Comment: @KingKing but sub string in the TO_STRUCTURE_NAME name must contains **CAB:DSLAM** then the next filter goes. Is there any other approach.

Comment: @KingKing XML structure is fixed there will be no variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is potential plase where you can get that exception

```
x => x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME").Contains("CAB:DSLAM")
```

You can fix your code using something like this:

```
.Where(x => ((x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME") == null) 
         ? fasle :
           x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME").Contains("CAB:DSLAM")) && ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what's wrong by splitting up your query like this:

```
// renamed to keep it short
var data = XMLOperations.TransmediaTable.AsEnumerable();
data = data.Where(x => x.Field<String>("TO_STRUCTURE_NAME").Contains("CAB:DSLAM"))
data = data.Where(x => x.Field<String>("BT_CABLE_TYPE") == "BFT")
data = data.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Field<String>("TO_EQUIPMENT_NAME")))
data = data.Where(x => ((x.Field<String>("BT_CABLE_DESIGNATION") + x.Field<String>("BT_CABLE_NUMBER")) == OnNumber))
data = data.Select(x => x.Field<String>("TRANSMEDIA_NAME"));
```

You will be able to find out easily what's going on there, because on debugging you'll be told by the IDE exactly where the exception is originating from.